# Find all the objects that does not have any reverse lookup m2m values

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset, django-1.7

I have a list of contacts and each Contact can belong to many ContactList. What I need to do is find all contacts that does not belong to any ContactList (ie. orphan contacts).

```
class ContactList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact)

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work, because contactlist_set is a reverse lookup field and not a model field.

```
Contact.objects.filter(contactlist_set=None)
```

Can some give me some direction to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this: `Contact.objects.filter(contactlist__isnull=False)` ?

Comment: @nik_m i got FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'contactlist', Contact do not have a direct field relate to ContactList

Comment: Just tested it locally and it works. Are you sure it fails?

Comment: May me because I used dj 1.7

Comment: What other `choices` you get in the traceback?

Comment: active, created, email, email_enabled, facility, facility_id, id, modified, module_context, name, notes, site, site_id, sms_enabled, sms_number, user, user_id, voice_enabled, voice_number (this is my full model)

Comment: That's strange! I don't believe this is a Django's version related. Does the m2m table exists (the one that connects `Contact` with `ContactList`?

Comment: the through table is there

Comment: So, you've got a through table. You didn't mention that! Please post that also.

Comment: it's the auto generated table not manual through table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138360/discussion-between-nik-m-and-du-d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
Contact.objects.filter(contactlist__isnull=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!